# file_put_contents appending data on a file being written by another process

Tags: php, unix, php-5.6, file-locking

I have

```
$bytesCount = file_put_contents( "somefile.log", "some text\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );
```

What happens if another process is writing** on `somefile.log`?

Does `file_put_contents` fails with a runtime error ?

Does if fails with `$bytesCount === false`

Or does does it pause the script until the file is unlocked and then performs the write operation?

---

(**) *or more generally another process has an exclusive lock on the file*

---

[ *I'm on a `*nix` platform with php 5.6* ]

Comment: If you have multiple processes (PHP Apps) that do write to the file using the same `file_get_contents`, you can pass the parameter: `LOCK_EX`, which is to acquire an exclusive lock on the file while proceeding to the writing. In other words, a flock() call happens between the fopen() call and the fwrite() call. This is not identical to an fopen() call with mode "x".

Comment: You are already doing it. If it cannot write to the file (another process is using it), the it fails. Coz, This function returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `file_put_contents` attempts to write on a locked file **waits until the file is unlocked then performs the write** and returns the number of bytes written.

---

**Proof:**

I wrote a simple two-scripts test:

the first script writes a 100MB file (on a slow USB2-connected drive);

the second script appends a short string to the same file.

The *core* of the two scripts are these four lines:

```
echo Milliseconds() . ": Start writing file on file\n";
$bytesCount = file_put_contents( "/Volumes/myHD/somefile.txt", $buffer, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );
var_export( $bytesCount );
echo "\n" . Milliseconds() . ": Done writing on file\n";
```

Where `Milliseconds()` is a function that returns the current unix timestamp in milliseconds.

In the first script `$buffer` is a 100MB string, in the second script `$buffer = "MORE-DATA\n";`

Running the first script and quickly starting the second one result in this output:

**Script 1:**

```
$ php test1.php
1481892766645: Start writing file on file
100000000
1481892769680: Done writing on file
$
```

**Script 2:**

```
$ php test2.php
1481892766831: Start writing file on locked file
10
1481892769909: Done writing file on locked file
$
```

Note that:

- the second script attempted writing 186 ms after the first one but before the second script was done writing. So the second script actually accessed a locked file.
- the second script termiated writing 229 ms after the first one

**Checking the result after both scripts terminated execution:**

```
$ stat -f%z /Volumes/myHD/somefile.txt 
100000010
$
```

10MB + 10 bytes were written

```
$ tail -c 20 /Volumes/myHD/somefile.txt
0123456789MORE-DATA 
$
```

The second script actually appended the string at the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

It should be obvious that this should only be used if you're making one write, if you are writing multiple times to the same file you should handle it yourself with fopen and fwrite, the fclose when you are done writing.

Benchmark below:

file_put_contents() for 1,000,000 writes - average of 3 benchmarks:

real 0m3.932s
user 0m2.487s
sys 0m1.437s

fopen() fwrite() for 1,000,000 writes, fclose() -  average of 3 benchmarks:

real 0m2.265s
user 0m1.819s
sys 0m0.445s

For overwriting when using ftp, this is helpful:

```
/* create a stream context telling PHP to overwrite the file */ 
$options = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true)); 
$stream = stream_context_create($options);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php